# mysql connection string over domain

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i made application using VB.Net and everything is working fine on my PC at home, i wanted to start using it at my work network i installed mysql community on windows 2012 server with successful connection and that server is under domain and i logged in as admin
when i setup my application on the other machines of users i got message of unable to connect with mysql.. my understanding of this is the problem with my connection string the connection string i used is

if i try the connection string on the server machine it will work and connect

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=mmm123;database=dam;sslMode=none")
```

OR

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=mmm123;database=dam;sslMode=none")
```

but on user machine it will not it will give unable message and i even tried using ip address but still the same problem

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=xx.xx.xx.xx;userid=root;password=mmm123;database=dam;sslMode=none")
```

can you please lead me from where i should start with
thank you in advance

Comment: bad idea for starters vb.net applications can be decompiled/disassembled so they know your MySQL username/password directly .. Ideally you need to expose the MySQL tables on a webservice/serversocket on the server where the vb.net client application can connect and use..

Comment: Without the exact error message I can only suggest you to look at this list of possible errors. I would look carefully at  point 5 and 6. See https://razorsql.com/docs/mysql_connection_troubleshooting.html

Comment: *"I would look carefully at point 5 and 6"* dont forget 7 and 8 @Steve  ... Also NAT ("port forwarding") can be a thing here i assume the topicstarter has a router at home.. Anny how this question is not really [ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here..

Comment: thanks guys for reply.. the error message i got is (unable to connect to the specified mysql hosts)

Comment: as i understand from the answers using localhost as server name is okay but i need to look for mysql configuration .. i will look deeper and keep reading about it.. thank u guys

Comment: You might need to open ports in the server's firewall: [MySQL Port Reference Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html) - and it might be a good idea to use SSL. Also, [MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Comment: actually the port 3306 is already opened in the firewall but about SSL in MySQL Workbench it's set as (if available) i did not make it as required but i will try it

Comment: The most common problem that I see is the missing configuration for your userid that allows it to connect from another machine. So you need to use the MySql management interface (MySqlWorkbench) to add the user to the list of the users allowed to connect. Of course, when the app is not on the same machine where the mysql server runs then you need to change the IP address in your connection string to match the server IP.

Comment: sorry for asking about things i know it's basics but i'm new to this and it's my first VB.net app and first time with mysql and networking world it took a lot of time and searching and studying until finally i could run it locally and i hope soon i can make it run on my the network of my work facility.. thank you for the quick response guys

Comment: hello guys i found out that my problem is with a PRIVILEGES, i created a new user a superuser, and i provided it with full root access to everything in the database, which means to GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES.. i'm sorry if i was not describing my problem well but i really appreciated all replies .. god bless you all:)